# When adding a node, the site images do not show

Tags: 7, nodes, media

I have some image links that are inside standard `<a href>` tags, that link to some external sites. Example:
`<a href="http://http://www.webbdeepsky.com/" title="The Webb Deep Sky Society" target="_blank"><img class="supporter-logo" src="assets/images/webds.png" alt="Bedford Astronomical Society - Supporters of The Webb Deep Sky Society"></a>`

The images display no problem, until I go to add a node of my custom content type "Front Page Announcement". Then, the images do not display - i.e. the path to the image cannot be found.

I URL I get is: `http://localhost/bedsastro_new/node/add/front-page-announcement`
And the images are in `assets/site-images/`

When I look at at where the browser is expecting the image to be, it's :
`http://localhost/bedsastro_new/node/add/front-page-annoucement/assets/site-images/pic.jpg`

How do I ensure that Drupal is looking at right location for the images (i.e. `http://localhost/bedsastro_new/assets/site-images/pic.jpg`) ?

Thanks!
Daz

Comment: Your `img` src needs to be `/assets/images/webds.png`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the root of your Drupal site is `http://localhost/bedsastro_new/` .

To reference an image with filename `pic.jpg` (using an `img` tag) which is located in the site's subfolder named `assets/site-images`, you should specify `/assets/site-images/pic.jpg` as the value of the `src` attribute within the `img` tag.

With that, Drupal will try to find that image at `http://localhost/bedsastro_new/assets/site-images/pic.jpg`, which is where your image is actually located, so that should work.

Comment: Oh, I can't believe I missed that!! Thank you Pierre, for spotting my mistake!  I am still learning Drupal and I figured I had done (or not done) something in a setting somwehere!!

Comment: Except..... having changed the `img src` path to include the backslash, now the images on ANY page do not show.... The path for the images is now `http://localost/assets/site-images/` - the `bedsastro_new` part of the path has been removed from all the `img` tags

Comment: I'm not sure I understand HOW you changed the "img src". What is the purpose of this pic.jpg? What is the purpose of those image links? If you change that link in 1 specific node, how can that be related to "now the images on ANY page do not show"? Also, in your .htaccess file, what have you specified for the line continaing "RewriteBase" (typically around line 106)?

Comment: Hi Pierre, Yes, perhaps I'm not being clear enough..  I have a block which contains 5 small images, wrapped in `<a href>` tags to link to other sites. This block sits in one of the footer regions of the theme. If you look at http://bedsastro.org.uk it is the right-hand region of the footer. I am revising the site with a new theme.

Comment: So, after your initial post, I updates the code in the block to read `<a href="http://http://www.webbdeepsky.com/" title="The Webb Deep Sky Society" target="_blank"><img class="supporter-logo" src="/assets/images/webds.png" alt="Bedford Astronomical Society - Supporters of The Webb Deep Sky Society"></a>` with the / in the `src` element.

Comment: This then stopped the images from being displayed on any page. Without the leading slash, the images display on all pages EXCEPT when logged in as an Author role and creating a new node of content type Front Page Announcement (I have a View on the home page to show these announcements)

Comment: Line 106 for the Rewrite rule is currently commented out. The folder structure is `c:\web\bedsastro_new`. My localhost web root is `c:\web`. I have tested the original site (c:\web\bedsastro) and have the same issue - I had just not noticed it before!  Thanks for your patience, Pierre

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution - or at least A solution!

I updated the paths for the images to use
    `<?php print base_path(); >/asset/site-images/image.jpg`

And this worked :)